# Win32 DatePicker setting max date not working

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a win32 GUI application with a date picker control. I can set the minimum date, but the maximum date never takes. Here is the code I am using to set the max, and then check the max:

```
void setMaximum(HWND hwnd, SYSTEMTIME st)
{
    LRESULT rc = SendMessageW(hwnd, DTM_SETRANGE, GDTR_MAX, (LPARAM)&st);

    SYSTEMTIME st2;
    LRESULT rc2 = SendMessageW(hwnd, DTM_GETRANGE, GDTR_MAX, (LPARAM)&st2);
}
```

I stopped the debugger and get the following results:

```
    rc  0   __int64
    rc2 1   __int64
    st  {wYear=2020 wMonth=7 wDayOfWeek=3 ...}  _SYSTEMTIME
       wYear            2020    unsigned short
       wMonth           7   unsigned short
       wDayOfWeek       3   unsigned short
       wDay             22  unsigned short
       wHour            1   unsigned short
       wMinute          8   unsigned short
       wSecond          48  unsigned short
       wMilliseconds    866 unsigned short
    st2 {wYear=1601 wMonth=1 wDayOfWeek=1 ...}  _SYSTEMTIME
       wYear            1601    unsigned short
       wMonth           1   unsigned short
       wDayOfWeek       1   unsigned short
       wDay             1   unsigned short
       wHour            0   unsigned short
       wMinute          0   unsigned short
       wSecond          0   unsigned short
       wMilliseconds    0   unsigned short
```

Obviously `SendMessageW` is failing given that `rc` is zero, but the `SYSTEMTIME` struct contents all looks valid going in. I thought I was doing something wrong so I tried changing `GDTR_MAX` to `GDTR_MIN` and it works perfectly. I have been through the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-datetime_setrange) but replaced the MACRO `DateTime_SetRange` with the underlying calls when it failed in the hopes of getting a helpful return code.

Am I doing something incorrectly and just getting lucky with setting the minimum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DTM_SETRANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/dtm-setrange) and [`DTM_GETRANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/dtm-getrange) messages both expect the `LPARAM` to be a pointer to a `SYSTEMTIME[2]` array, but you are giving them both a pointer to a single `SYSTEMTIME` instead.  That is why `DTM_SETRANGE` works when using only `GDTR_MIN`, since the *minimum* `SYSTEMTIME` is the 1st element in the array.

The `wParam` of `DTM_SETRANGE` specifies which element(s) of the array are being set.  You are telling `DTM_SETRANGE` that you are setting the 2nd array element, but you are not passing in a 2nd element, so it is getting garbage from surrounding memory of the `st` parameter, and that is why `DTM_SETRANGE` fails and returns 0.

The `wParam` of `DTM_GETRANGE` is not used. The return value specifies which element(s) were returned.  `GDTR_MIN` is 1, which is what you are seeing `DTM_GETRANGE` returning.

Try this instead:

```
void setMaximum(HWND hwnd, SYSTEMTIME st)
{
    SYSTEMTIME arr[2] = {};
    arr[1] = st;
    LRESULT rc = SendMessageW(hwnd, DTM_SETRANGE, GDTR_MAX, (LPARAM)&arr);
    LRESULT rc2 = SendMessageW(hwnd, DTM_GETRANGE, 0, (LPARAM)&arr);
}
```

Comment: Wow, the documentation is not very clear about that. It makes sense when you spell it out. What if you only want to set the max, is the interface expecting you must also set the min, or is it not looking at the 0th element?

Comment: @steveo225 "*Wow, the documentation is not very clear about that*" - Yes, it is. Read it again more carefully: (DTM_SETRANGE) "*wParam **A value specifying which range values are valid**... lParam **A pointer to a two-element array of SYSTEMTIME structures**. The first element of the SYSTEMTIME array contains the minimum allowable time. The second element of the SYSTEMTIME array contains the maximum allowable time. **It is not necessary to fill an array element that is not specified in the wParam parameter**.*" ...

Comment: @steveo225 ... (DTM_GETRANGE) "*lParam **A pointer to a two-element array of SYSTEMTIME structures**. ... Returns a DWORD value that is a combination of GDTR_MIN or GDTR_MAX. The first element of the SYSTEMTIME array contains the minimum allowable time if GDTR_MIN is set. The second element of the SYSTEMTIME array contains the maximum allowable time if GDTR_MAX is set.*"

Comment: @steveo225 "*What if you only want to set the max, is the interface expecting you must also set the min, or is it not looking at the 0th element?*" - It sets what you tell it to set. Look at the example I gave you, it doesn't set a min.  You can set the min and max independantly, but you still have to use a `SYSTEMTIME[2]` array each time.

Comment: I meant that is wasted clear to me, I saw the 2-element pointer, I thought that meant if you were trying to set BOTH a min and max. "It is not necessary to fill an array element that is not specified in the flags parameter" lead me to think it wasn't required to exist, not that it must exist but isn't required to be set. It seemed too weird that the interface was requiring 2 elements even when it wasn't going to access one of them. Why require it? Now that it has been cleared up, I understand the interface, but it stills seems weird to require 2. I am not always good at explaining my thoughts.

Comment: @steveo225 it makes the interface easier to work with if you just pass in a `SYSTEMTIME[2]` every time, instead of conditionally either a `SYSTEMTIME` or a `SYSTEMTIME[2]` depending on the input. Logically, they could have defined a `DTM_(GET|SET)MINMAX` for single-item input/output, but they didn't

Comment: In my case, I have a "to" and "from" control, so when "to" is changed, I send the SYSTEMTIME in the notify event as the minimum for "from", and vice versa, setting the selection in "from" as the maximum for "to", so I only ever have one. Making a temporary array of 2 worked. Thanks